# Appending separate div to cloned draggable

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to append a separate div to a cloned draggable div.

This jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kdfiddle/26fuvqxe/

Does exactly what I want it to - EXCEPT - I want the draggables to be cloned.

**The Problem**
is when I use `helper: 'clone',` and try to append the separate div to the clone:
http://jsfiddle.net/kdfiddle/o446vwas/

The div I want to have appended - does not attach - unless you click and drag the same Box# twice. On the second click and drag it then does what I expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to append when you start drag, clone and add draggable to the cloned div when you stop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".box").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).append($("#appendable_div"));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).addClass('box-cloned').clone(true).appendTo('body');
      $(".box-cloned").on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).draggable({
          start: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).append($("#appendable_div"));
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#draggables {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box, .box-cloned {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 150px;
}

#appendable_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="appendable_div">
  appendable div
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="draggables">

  <div class="box">Box #1</div>
  <div class="box">Box #2</div>
  <div class="box">Box #3</div>
  <div class="box">Box #4</div>

</div>
Drag a box above, to have the appendable div ... append to the box being dragged
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel H - but it is the boxes, Box #1, #2 etc.. that I want cloned.
I have nothing against cloning the red div as well - but the point was to clone the boxes - and append the red box to the cloned boxes. Thanks.

Comment: @Creeperstanson ok this will work, check the updated answer =D

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much :) So the trick is to append to the ui clone helper 'ui.helper'? Does that sound about right?